# Tomcat port redirect not works in version 6.0.28

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, port

I am using tomcat 6.0.28 and trying to redirect the port to another port but not works.

```
<Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" debug="3"
   disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" 
   maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="WebServer" 
   port="8092" redirectPort="8559"/>

<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
   connectionTimeout="20000" debug="0" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" 
   keystoreFile="./conf/selfsigned.pfx" keystorePass="adventnet" keystoreType="PKCS12" 
   maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" name="SSL" port="8559" 
   scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

**Added the above two lines in server.xml in conf folder.**

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secured Core Context</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**And added the above block to web.xml in conf folder, But port redirection not works.**

If I do the same in fresh tomcat it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your port definition lacks `protocol` attribute. Add `protocol="HTTP/1.1"` for the HTTP connector.

In the case of HTTPS connector you have to decide what implementation do you want, but if you look at default tomcat conf, you will find `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"` for HTTPS.

Comment: I tried adding both the protocol attributes in connectors, redirection not works